# Edit a custom admin page

Tags: customization, php, options

I have created a custom admin menu page with: `add_menu_page`

This page uploads a form to the wp_options table in the database.
Basic save with `update_option` like:

```
function addressbook_save (){
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
// get the option
$customer = get_option( 'customer' );
// add new data to the option
$customer[] = $_POST['customer'];
// save it back to the db
update_option( 'customer', $customer );
}
```

I also show the data from that form on the same page with a foreach-loop.

Here comes the problem:
I want to be able to create a button that let's me eddit the uploaded data.
Maybe I'm just working on this to long to understand why I can't get this to work

Comment: When you load the page, could you get the options and place them inside an input box? A similar method used when dealing with Custom Meta. Then the button would just submit the form, updating or adding the option.

Comment: Howdy: Yeah but that's the lame solution. I also need to delete records. I can't expect my users to empty out the fields and save them

Comment: What kind of "cool" solution are you looking for? You could create a javascript button click to empty the field for them if you really wanted to I guess.

Comment: I'm nog looking for a "cool" solution. I'm looking for a user-friendly solution. You have to agree with me that it's really unacceptable to let the user clear out the fields and save the form again. By the way there will be so many empty fields in the db... You get the point.